# Simple.Data - how to bi-drectionally join on the same table twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple.data

I know I'm close with this one...

My structure is:

I have some companies
Each company has a primary user (account)
And a list of all users (accounts).

I've implemented this in the db as a companies table that has "Primary" as a foreign key to the Accounts table, and the Accounts table has a CompanyId which is a foreign key to the Companies table.

So there's only ever one primary user, and each user is associated with one company.

I want to retrieve a list of all companies, and plonk them in a c# object. What I have so far is:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> GetAllCompaniesList()
    {
        var allData = database.Companies.All()
            .Join(database.Accounts).On(database.Accounts.Id == database.Companies.Primary)
            .Join(database.Accounts).On(database.Accounts.CompanyId == database.Companies.Id)
            .ToList<Company>();
        return allData;
    }
```

and it works in my tests using an in-memory adapter with the relevant keys set up, but not in the real version, crashing out with

> The objects "dbo.Accounts" and "dbo.Accounts" in the FROM clause have
>   the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

I think this means I need to name each join (e.g. to make sql like "join a on a = b as c"), but I can't find the syntax to do that. Anyone know?

Comment: If you want to retrieve a list of all Companies, why are you joining onto Accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias table names using the `.As` method. In addition to that, the Join method has an optional second `out` parameter which puts the reference to the aliased table in a dynamic variable; it just makes referring to the table easier.

So try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> GetAllCompaniesList()
{
    dynamic primary;
    var allData = database.Companies.All()
        .Join(database.Accounts.As("PrimaryAccounts"), out primary)
            .On(primary.Id == database.Companies.Primary)
        .Join(database.Accounts)
            .On(database.Accounts.CompanyId == database.Companies.Id)
        .ToList<Company>();
    return allData;
}
```

That should work fine.