# Simple.Data One Direction Join on a Table Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, join, simple.data

I have a Users table and a Messages table.  The Messages table has two foreign key references to the Users table, "To_Id" and "From_Id" both pointing to User.Id.  I want to write a query that will return the messages and allow me to get the Username property from both the User represented by the To and From relations.  Here's what I have so far:

```
dynamic sender;
dynamic recipient;
var messages= db.Messages.All(db.Messages.To_Id == currentUser.Id || db.Messages.From_Id == currentUser.Id)
    .Join(db.Users.As("Sender"), out sender).On(sender.Id == db.Messages.From_Id)
    .Join(db.Users.As("Recipient"), out recipient).On(recipient.Id == db.Messages.To_Id)
return messages;
```

The result of this query gives me the correct Messages count, but the To_Id and From_Id columns disappear and the Sender and Recipient column names also do not appear.  I tried looking at the docs, the source on github and this question here: [Simple.Data - how to bi-drectionally join on the same table twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110898/simple-data-how-to-bi-drectionally-join-on-the-same-table-twice) without any success yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what could be happening to your To_Id and From_Id columns, but if you want to eager-load the Users rows, you need to add With clauses:

```
dynamic sender;
dynamic recipient;
var messages= db.Messages.All(db.Messages.To_Id == currentUser.Id || db.Messages.From_Id == currentUser.Id)
    .Join(db.Users.As("Sender"), out sender).On(sender.Id == db.Messages.From_Id)
    .Join(db.Users.As("Recipient"), out recipient).On(recipient.Id == db.Messages.To_Id)
    .With(sender)
    .With(recipient);
return messages;
```

As for the missing columns, have you tried looking at the Trace to see the SQL that's being executed for the query? That might help to shed some light.